# Magento 1.9 - Placing order before paypal payment

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, paypal-standard

I've a problem with paypal integration in magento. 
If i choose paypal standard payment and confirm order, i'm correctly redirected to paypal site for payment, but if i press back button on the browser i am redirected in /checkout/cart (that is empty) and in my backend my order was placed and in PENDING status (it's not shown in customers order list)...
This happens because the order were placed before payment processing...
In OnepageController.php saveOrderAction method i can see

```
$this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->save();
    /**
     * when there is redirect to third party, we don't want to save order yet.
     * we will save the order in return action.
     */
    if (isset($redirectUrl)) {
        $result['redirect'] = $redirectUrl;
    }
```

What does it mean? It is exactly what i want "Don't want to save order yet....", unfortunately few rows before...

```
$this->getOnepage()->saveOrder();

$redirectUrl = $this->getOnepage()->getCheckout()->getRedirectUrl();
```

And the order was already placed....

I hate editing core files, but i've tried to comment out the line above, but an exception shows me that order information are used inside paypal module itself (Standard.php file method getStandardCheckoutFormFields). So i can't modify core file easily.
What am I missing?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? Running into the same issue